# Cannot access ports behind VPC on AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, mongodb, amazon-vpc, coreos

I am running two servers on a VPC in AWS.  One is an ubuntu server running mongodb on port `27017` and the only *public* port is `22`.  On a separate CoreOS server I have several containers that are supposed to connect to this database, the only public ports on this server are `80`, `443` and `22`.  I don't believe it is an issue with the containers because I can't even curl the database and get the default mongo `:27017` don't curl message on the host CoreOS machine.  I've bound mongo to `0.0.0.0` and I can access Mongo on it's own machine using both `127.0.0.1` and it's private IP. I am certain both servers are in the same VPC, they are also in the same availability zone as well.  What would cause the coreos to not be able to access the Mongo server?  Additionally all outbound traffic is allowed on both.

Comment: iptables or other firewall on the mongodb host? Security group on the mongodb host?

Comment: no other firewalls or iptables.  If they're on the same VPC what difference would the security group make?

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski hosts in the same VPC are not exempt from Security Group rules.

Comment: So I have to specify certain ports to open to everything on my cluster?!

Comment: If you want to allow all communication between VPC members, you can set up a SG to do just that.

Comment: Care to give example field input as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to make a rule in the security group.  So I added the security group ID that the CoreOS box belongs to a rule exposing 27017 to it in the Mongo server's security group